# RESTful API keys suggestions

Tags: rest, authentication, api-design, api-key

I'm looking for suggestions about a RESTful API design. I've read a lot about REST API schemes, ways of authentication/authorization etc. What I can't decide is if I really need to use API keys. From what I understand using API keys is useful if you want to monitor the usage, limit each application's requests and for statistical data.

What I want to avoid is having to create additional web interfaces for adding/managing/removing applications and adding/removing application administrators. Maybe there's a simpler way to do the API key distribution. Or do I really need those? I mean, monitoring and limiting the usage is cool and sounds useful but does it deserve the other things I need to make for keys distribution.

To be more specific my website is something like slideshare and scribd. I want to give API access to its functions like adding and managing documents and getting information about users. So for example to upload a file you need to somehow authenticate and use a specific account to do it. In this case is an API key a requirement or I can just stick with authenticating users?

So what do you think is the best way for me to handle API keys? Or should I use them at all? Is there a more clever way to distribute (create, remove) the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well do you know mashery http://www.mashery.com/ and programmableweb?

maybe there are some useful ressources
http://www.mashery.com/solution/collegeboard

and 
http://www.3scale.net/

i would use api keys for statistics and limitation but also serve some services without an api key like google does

You can create easily APIs with solutions like

Restler http://luracast.com/products/restler/

Frapi http://getfrapi.com/
The Datatank http://thedatatank.com/
Services (just for Drupal) http://drupal.org/project/services

there are some more: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/

Comment: I checked those links you put here. I don't want to use external services (even if they are free ones). And about using api key for some services and not using it for others, doesn't it defeat the purpose of the API key?

Comment: well google does it like this for several years and many other ones too, well than you have also to write your own (if there doesnt exist already one around the web sourceforge etc) api management software. Limiting everything with an api key (dont know who your hoster is) is much better, so you can control the usage completely so the risk of an abuse of your software is much lower and the security higher. or everyone can use it without an api key and can do whatever they want (and eventually bring down your server with to much requests per hour). i think the security is more important.

Comment: Ok you answered WHY I should use an API key. How about the way to use it? If I give an API to everyone who requests one won't it allow them to switch those and still do bad stuff?

Comment: well there are several other things like server ip, user ip and so on what you can check also

Comment: If you issue API keys with a lot of blanket rights then obviously they could be compromised nd those rights confered to others. But this doesn't make them invalid - there are different authentication patterns you can use - API Key, ID's + Keys, Keys for the App, oAuth and Logins for the user, each of which could have restrictions. It sounds like you app has end users so it's most likely good to have identies of the 3rd party apps logged + the identities of the user accounts being accessed.

Answer (score 2):

I answered in the post above too - but ran out of space. As a disclaimer I work for 3scale (http://www.3scale.net) so you might want to parse my response based on that :).

The answer to your question really depends on what resources your API exposes and what you're aiming to track/limit. It sounds like most functions are tied to a user account of some kind, but could be implemented by 3rd parties.

In this case the most useful pattern is probably to have an identifier (public or secret) for each application which calls the API + also user credentials. The application identifier could be an APIKey or even just a name (e.g. "tweetdeck"). If you end up with a lot of third party applications then it is probably useful to track these identifiers (which implies a minimum a way to issue them) and know who built each app + have the ability to turn them off (if only to shut down those that abuse your user-base). You might also want to rate the limit the amount of traffic each user and app can generate on the API, so it's again useful to have an identifier.

Also, if your authenticating users, but allowing third parties to write the apps your users use, definitely consider oAuth (http://www.oauth.net) to avoid rogue code / sites capturing your user passwords.

You mention above that you're not keen on external services - no problem, 3scale works by actually doing all the API auth local to your systen (e.g. with one of the code plugins: https://support.3scale.net/libraries or in a proxy like Varnish: https://github.com/3scale/libvmod-3scale/) and then does tracking in the cloud. Obviously it doesn't fit all use cases, but can give you a bunch of useful tools out of the box.

Comment: Thanks :) ! I will consider 3scale when I need to make something like this again as the project I was asking about is already done.