# Writing my own RESTful API. Are there any tutorials on how to handle API keys?

Tags: rest, api-key

I'm currently in the development phase of writing my own RESTful API, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding information/tutorials on how to handle API keys.  My Google searching only brings me to canned examples of REST, but *without* any mention or examples of how keys can/should be created/stored/used.

Any links to quality tutorials and/or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful API keys suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004068/restful-api-keys-suggestions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Brian Mulloy's posting at

**API Design: Deciphering Security**
https://blog.apigee.com/detail/api_design_deciphering_security

Which also links to Greg Brail's OAuth implementation overview at

**OAuth: Implementing OAuth 2.0**
https://blog.apigee.com/detail/oauth_implementing_oauth_2.0